# Is there a function such that $f' = f\circ f$?

Tags: calculus, functions

> Is there a function $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow (0,\infty)$, such that $f' = f\circ f$?

Apparently, I should assume by contradiction there is, and then it should imply that $f$ is increasing but I can't see the reason for that.

### EDIT:

Now, we know that $f(0)$ is a lower bound for $f'(x).\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$.
The next claim is for $x<0.f(x) <f(0) + xf(0) = (1+x)f(0)$.

Why it the last claim true?

Comment: Look at the codomain of your function.

Comment: @AlexR With your example $f\circ f= id \neq f'$, also your f is not defined for $x=0$

Comment: Well, if $f'(t) = f(f(t))$, and $f: \mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$, then $f'(t) > 0$, so $f$ is increasing everywhere.

Comment: if you assume $f\left(x\right)=(Cx)^{p}$ for some $C,p\in\mathbb{C}$ you can see by comparison of the exponents that $p-1=p^{2}$, thus $p=\frac{1}{2}\pm\sqrt{\frac{1}{4}-1}$ now $C$ should be easy to adjust.

Comment: @Max The obtained values of $p$ in your suggestion doesn't lead to positive real-valued functions. So, in a sense, it negates the possibility that $f$ can be a polynomial function :-)

Comment: hmmm... i start to believe that there really is no such function. maybe this can be adopted to a local argument around zero using taylor to get a contradiction? (just a vague idea if you don't have anything to try, i had a long day and need a break from math puzzling so i will not try it)

Answer (score 4):

Observe $f'$ is strictly positive, and so $f$ is monotonically increasing.  Thus $f'$ is a monotonically increasing function as well, so we can continuously extend $f$ and $f'$ to $-\infty$, and furthermore we must have $f'(-\infty) = 0$.

Then,

$$0 = \lim_{x \to -\infty} f'(x) = \lim_{x \to -\infty} f(f(x))
= f(\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)) $$

Since $f(x) > 0$ for all real $x$, we must have

$$\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x) = -\infty $$

which is absurd.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I don't quite understand. Why must $f'(-\infty) = 0$? Is it because $f$ is strictly nondecreasing?

Comment: @Cameron: Yes: differentiable + monotone + bounded implies the limit exists, and the limit of the derivative also exists and is $0$.

Comment: Got it! Thanks. This is a very nice solution.

Comment: @Cameron: Hrm. Except I'm doubting myself now that I've said it. I think I can still find counterexamples even with monotone. $0$ has to be a limit point of the derivative, but I'm no longer convinced it is the only limit point. Grr, now I'm annoyed that I don't remember what the actual conditions I need are!

Comment: @Cameron: $f'$ being nondecreasing is sufficient too. I'm certain there's a useful, more general condition but it's not springing to mind. :(

Comment: Why must $f'$ be monotonic as well? Can we conclude it from the fact that $f''(x) = (f\circ f)'(x) = f'(f(x))f'(x) = f'(f(x))f(f(x)) > 0$?

Comment: @Cameron: the composite of monotonic functions is monotonic: e.g. in the case of a nondecreasing function $g$ and nonincreasing function $h$, $$x \leq y \implies g(x) \leq g(y) \implies h(g(x)) \geq h(g(y)) $$

Comment: Oh that makes complete sense.

Comment: @Hurkyl How do you get "Since $f(x) > 0$ for all real $x$ ..." I do not see how it leads you to conclude that "we must have
$$
  \lim_{x \to - \infty} f(x) = - \infty".
$$

Comment: @Singhal: $f(\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)) = 0$. Therefore, $\lim_{x \to -\infty} f(x)$ cannot be any value $L$ for which $f(L) > 0$. There are surely other paths to the contradiction, but that's the one I used.

Comment: Oh! I get it now. So perhaps a better way to put it will be "Since $f(x) > 0$ for all real $x$ and $f$ is monotonic, therefore we must have $\lim_{x \to - \infty} f(x) < r$ for all $r \in \Bbb{R}$. In other words, $\lim_{x \to - \infty} f(x) = - \infty$ which is absurd.

Answer (score 3):

To answer your specific question: try the fundamental theorem of calculus.  Since $f$ is increasing, you know that $f\circ f$ is also increasing, and therefore $f'$ is as well.  Therefore, fixing $x$, $f'(x)$ is larger than $f'(y)$ for any $y\lt x$ and since $f'(y) \lt f'(x)$, $\int_0^xf'(y)dy\lt\int_0^xf'(x)dy$ - but the former is $f(x)-f(0)$ and the latter is $xf'(x)$.  This gives $f(x)-f(0)\lt xf'(x)$, or $f(x)\lt f(0)+xf'(x)\lt f(0)+xf(0)$, with the last inequality coming by the already-proved result on $f'(x)$.