# There is no function from $\mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$ satisfying $f'(x)=f(f(x))$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-equations

**Problem:** Prove that there is no differentiable function from $\mathbb{R} \to (0, \infty)$ satisfying $f'(x)=f(f(x))$.

I could not make much progress, except for observing that any derivatives (any order, whenever they exist) are always positive.

Please help. Even hints are appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a function such that $f' = f\circ f$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/687488/is-there-a-function-such-that-f-f-circ-f)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f$ outputs positive numbers, $f'$ must be positive. Since $f'=f\circ f$, then $f''$ exists, and $f''=\left(f'\circ f\right)\cdot f'$, and you can see that $f''$ is also positive. With $f$, $f'$, and $f''$ positive on $\mathbb{R}$, $f$ must have a horizontal asymptote $y=c\geq0$ as $x\to-\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f'(x)=0$. (Formal proof below.) Then $$f(c)=\lim_{x\to-\infty}f(f(x))=\lim_{x\to-\infty}f'(x)=0$$ and it is not permitted that $f(c)=0$.

---

With $f$ and $f'$ positive, $f$ is bounded below and increasing. This guarantees $c$ exist, and gives the existence of the horizontal asymptote. But it isn't automatic that $\lim_{x\to-\infty}f'(x)$ exists. For example, maybe the curve is flat as it moves left, and occasionally, for very brief periods, takes on a very steep slope. This is why (as Greg Martin notes in the comments) we must make use of $f''$ being positive.

The logic is the same with $f'$ as was with $f$. Since $f'$ and $f''$ are positive, then $f'$ has a left asymptote at $y=d\geq0$. But $d$ must equal $0$ since otherwise $f$ wouldn't be bounded below.

Comment: Thanks! I should have been able to observe on my own that 'f must have a horizontal asymtote'.

Comment: It's important to note that $f'$ is increasing (since $f(f(x))$ is); otherwise it's not necessarily true that $\lim_{x\to-\infty} f'(x) = 0$.