# Prove that this function can't exist

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, derivatives, monotone-functions

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0,\infty)$ be a differentiable function such that $f'(x)=f(f(x))$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Prove that such a function can't exist.

All that I have found so far is that the functions $f$ and $f'$ are strictly increasing on $\mathbb{R}$. Also that $f''(x)>0$ and thus $f$ is strictly convex on $\mathbb{R}$. How do I proceed or exploit this monotonicity ?

Comment: Check these: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1743401/42969,  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/848627/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1120041/42969, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/408004/42969 – all found [with Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24f%27(x)%3Df(f(x))%24)

Comment: @Martin R Thank you! Didn't know about that site, really appreciated.

Comment: You are welcome. – More information here: [How to search with Approach0](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/29267/42969).